# jQuery: Triggering .click() events, one after the other

Tags: jquery

I have a situation where I have to do multiple actions on a page in order to initialize it's settings. I do not have any code yet for it because, frankly I am having trouble finding a place to start on it.

Here is what I want to do:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $('#element-one').trigger('click');
    // wait for the first trigger event to complete (it loads ajax content into a div tag)
    // then move on to this one...
    $('#element-two').trigger('click');
    // then move on to this one...
    $('#element-three').trigger('click');
    // then move on to this one...
    $('#element-four').trigger('click');
    // then finally move on to the last one
    $('#element-five').trigger('click');

});
```

How is this accomplished?

Comment: Have you considered calling the other triggers inside of the AJAX callback?

Comment: Why not create an Init() function that you call after the page loads which will call all functions being called in the click events

Answer (score 11):

inside your first handler you could use a deferred object, resolve it in the ajax success callback and return a promise so you would chain your code like this (I haven't tested)

```
 $.when(
    $('#element-one').triggerHandler('click') /* asynchronous task */
 ).done(function() {
     $('#element-two').triggerHandler('click') /* synchronous task */
     ...
     $('#element-five').triggerHandler('click') /* synchronous task */
 })
```

from http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/

> jQuery.Deferred(), introduced in version 1.5, is a chainable utility object that can register multiple callbacks into callback queues, invoke callback queues, and relay the success or failure state of any synchronous or asynchronous function.

Note: I used `triggerHandle()` instead of `trigger()`: http://api.jquery.com/triggerHandler/ just to be agnostic on elements to which you attached your handlers. Use `trigger()` as well if it's suitable for your needs