# How to execute alert after trigger click event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to execute the alert message after the execution of the trigger event. My code :

```
 $(".addpage").trigger("click").queue(function () { 
  alert($(".page:first-child").attr("id")); 
 });
```

But here problem is the alert is executing before completing the trigger event function. What i am doin wrong here?

Comment: What does triggering the `click` handlers do? Some animation or ajax? If you can edit the page source, your best solution is somewhere else.

Comment: Are you looking for like this one  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9026584/jquery-triggering-click-events-one-after-the-other

Comment: can u show us a demo at jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here i have done complete bins for above issue. please find demo link and check it out..

**Demo:** http://codebins.com/bin/4ldqp7m

**HTML**

```
<ul id="pages">
  <li class="page" id="1">
    Page-1
  </li>
  <li class="page" id="2">
    Page-2
  </li>
  <li class="page" id="3">
    Page-3
  </li>
  <li class="page" id="4">
    Page-4
  </li>
</ul>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function() {
    $(".addpage").click(function(e) {
        var newId = parseInt($("#pages li.page:last").attr('id')) + 1;
        $("#pages").append("<li class='page' id='" + (newId) + "'>Page-" + (newId) + "</li>");

    });
    $(".addpage").trigger('click');
    $(".addpage").queue(function() {
        alert("New Page with Id #" + $("#pages li.page:last").attr('id') + " has been added...!");
    });
});
```

**CSS:**

```
#pages{
  list-style:none;
  margin:5px;
  padding:2px;
  width:120px;

}
#pages li{
  border:1px solid #1A1A1A;
  width:120px;
  background:#4fdefd;
  text-align:center;

}
.addpage{
  background:#53a5f9;
  border:1px solid #1142fd;
}
.addpage:hover{
  background:#53cdfa;
}
```

**Demo:** http://codebins.com/bin/4ldqp7m

Answer (score 1):

With .queue(callback) you will add a new function to the end of the element's standard "fx" queue used for element effects (animations). So if the .click() event handler does not include any element animation, the .queue() callback will be effective immediately.